# how to make either of the two input fields mandatory using vuejs2/vuetify

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

So I am creating a contact form and I have following fields

1. Name
2. Email
3. Phone number

I want to make either email or phone number mandatory and not both

If email is not empty and is valid, phone number should not be mandatory

If phone number field is not empty and is valid, email should not be mandatory

here is my code
Template

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4"  >
         <v-text-field
             label="Name*"
             placeholder="Name*"
             v-model="field.name"
             outlined
             :rules="nameRules"
             dense
         ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>
     <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4"  >
         <v-text-field
             label="Email*"
             placeholder="Email*"
             v-model="field.email"
             :rules="emailRules"
             outlined
             dense
         ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>
     <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4"  >                 
          <v-text-field
             label="Phone Number*"
             placeholder="Phone Number*"
             v-model="field.phone"
             :rules="phoneRules"
             outlined
             dense
          ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>                       
</v-row>
```

script

```
export default ({ 
   data: () => ({
       nameRules: [
          v => !!v || 'This field is required',
       ],
       emailRules: [
          v => !!v || 'E-mail is required',
          v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'E-mail must be valid',
       ],
       phoneRules: [
          v => !!v || 'Phone Number is required',
          v => /^[\d ()+-]+$/.test(v) || 'Phone Number must be valid'
       ],
   })
})
```

Comment: Pass field to your rule function, check on both email or telephone. Use this rule on both fields.

Comment: @Wimanicesir how? i dont understand, can u show how using an example? Thanks